# hadoop fs -ls out of memory error

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have 300000+ files on a HDFS data directory.

When I do a hadoop fs -ls  and I am getting an out of memory error saying GC Limit has exceeded. The cluster nodes have 256 GB of RAM each. How do I fix it?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. We are not general database tech support. maybe try the DBA site.

Comment: Yes this is a pretty much programming topic if you understand what hadoop fs -ls does. I would be interested in knowing if fs -ls loads the file names as an array list and the list object is getting bigger. I have not gone through the source code so can not tell exactly. And sorry DBA may not help in this case.

Comment: @MarcB while I agree on the offtopic part, this is certainly not about a database (I've seen you close-voting about that on other questions already- Hadoop is not a damn database). SuperUser is the best address here. Hint: you can change the heap size of the jvm that runs the `ls` in the `hadoop` script. (Which is clearly an administration thing, not about programming at all).

Comment: Increasing heap never helped. Even if I do a count, it gives me an out of memory. I understand by having so many files may bring down the NN, but I thought using a MR script is a better way to concatenate them. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: @SambitTripathy it is unlikely that the out of memory error is propagating to your console client if it happens on the namenode side. In any case, you can easily see if a namenode dies after you issue the ls command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a python script to split the files into multiple directories and run through them. First of all what are you trying to achieve when you know you have 300000+ files in a directory. If you want to concatenate better arrange them into sub dirs.

Comment: There is a way to list hdfs folder with a many files: https://altiscale.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201988085-Out-of-Memory-Exception-When-Listing-an-HDFS-Directory

Answer (score 11):

You can make more memory available to the hdfs command by specifying 'HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS'

```
HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Xmx4g" hdfs dfs -ls /
```

Found here: http://lecluster.delaurent.com/hdfs-ls-and-out-of-memory-gc-overhead-limit/

This fixed the problem for me, I had over 400k files in one directory and needed to delete most but not all of them.